# Availability and Unavailability

Tags: writing-style

Is it right to say - Because of availability of someone meeting is cancelled or should we say Because of unavailability of someone meeting is cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your versions are clear enough, but it would be more fluent to say:

> The meeting is canceled because *X* is unavailable.

if you want to stress the cancellation, or:

> Because *X* is unavailable, the meeting is canceled.

if you want to stress *X*'s attendance.